# How to check if the contents of an array are in a table?

Tags: arrays, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Okay, let's say that we have a table games, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE games(
    game_name NVARCHAR2(20),
    owner NVARCHAR2(30),
    purchase DATE
);
```

And an "array" like this one:

```
CREATE TYPE array_ch1 IS OBJECT (game_name NVARCHAR2(20),purchase DATE);
/

CREATE TYPE array_ch2 IS TABLE OF array_ch1;
/
```

And on that array there would be values like 'GTA', '2019' and 'Pac-man', '2000'.

> I was trying to create a procedure that returns all the owners that have all the games in the given date.

I already have a function called "checkGame", that given one owner and variable of the type "array_ch1" returns 1 or 0 (1 if that owner has the game and at the right purchase date, 0 otherwise).

My original idea was to iterate through the table games and the array at the same time and keep checking if a certain user did actually have the right game with the right date, but I have no idea how to return the result, nor what to do in case there are more than one owners that match the criteria.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE findOwners(game_date IN array_ch2, good_owners OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS BEGIN
    FOR v_game in SELECT * FROM games LOOP
        FOR cond in 1..game_date.count LOOP
            IF(checkGame(cond, v_game.owner) = 0) THEN
                EXIT;
            END IF;
        END;
    END;
END;
/
```

Comment: What's the purpose of having the data in two places at once?

Comment: The idea was that user (through another software) was looking for games that match their criteria, @BobJarvis, maybe I should receive this kind of input in another way?

Comment: My point is that having your data in two places is a bad idea. Keep your data in the database, take it out to work on it, put it back when done.

Comment: @BobJarvis What do you suggest?

Comment: Get rid of the arrays. Query the database when you want to know what's there. Update the table as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use a SQL query, as your table type array_ch2 can be used in a query:

```
create table games(
   game_name NVARCHAR2(20),
    owner NVARCHAR2(30),
    purchase DATE
);

CREATE TYPE array_ch1 IS OBJECT (game_name NVARCHAR2(20),purchase DATE);
/

CREATE TYPE array_ch2 IS TABLE OF array_ch1;
/
insert into games values('Pacman', 'A', sysdate-300);
/
insert into games values('Pacman', 'A', sysdate-250);
/
insert into games values('GTA', 'A', sysdate-250);
/
insert into games values('Pacman', 'B', sysdate-2);
/
insert into games values('GTA', 'B', sysdate-1);
/
insert into games values('Pacman', 'C', sysdate-300);
/
insert into games values('Pacman', 'C', sysdate-400);
/
commit
/


declare
    game1 array_ch1:=array_ch1('Pacman', sysdate-100);
    game2 array_ch1:=array_ch1('GTA', sysdate-200);
    tgames array_ch2:=array_ch2(game1, game2);
    v_count pls_integer:=2;
    c_result sys_refcursor;
begin
    open c_result for 
      select games.owner
        from games, 
             table(tgames) tgames
       where games.game_name=tgames.game_name
         and games.purchase<=tgames.purchase
       group by owner
      having count(distinct games.game_name)=v_count;
end;
```

In the sample data, only A meets the condition, of having both games at the desired time, B has both games, but after the desired time, and C has 2 of the same games.